# Why setText() doesn't work when restoring state of the fragment

Tags: java, android, settext

I'm trying finish coding a tic tac toe app which use two instances of the same fragment communicating together so that every player can play on it's own grid [as show here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHhrw.jpg)(every grid is placed in a xml file that replace a framelayout in the main xml).
The app works correctly but I'm unable to restore the state of the app after rotation.
To do so I'm using a static `ArrayList` located in another class called `ArrayPersistence`:

```java
private static ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;

public ArrayPersistence(){}

public static void setStringArrayList(String[][] buttons)
{
    stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>(9);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            stringArrayList.add(buttons[i][y]);
        }
    //System.out.println(stringArrayList);
}

public static ArrayList<String> getStringArrayList()
{
    //System.out.println(stringArrayList);
    return stringArrayList;
}
```

With the method `onSaveInstanceState` I save the text showed on the buttons:

```java
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b)
{
    String[][] string = new String[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            string[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
        }
    }
    ArrayPersistence.setStringArrayList(string);

    int y = 1;
    b.putInt("rebooted", y);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
}
```

With `onActivityCreated` I try to restore the text

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(b);
    if(b != null)
    {
        if (b.getInt("rebooted") == 1)
        {
            ArrayList<String> string = ArrayPersistence.getStringArrayList();
            System.out.println("Arraylist printed by onActivityCreated: "+string);
            int i = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                {
                    i++
                    String s = string.get(i);
                    buttons[x][y].setText(s);//<--- Problem here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The bi-dimensional array is used to store the ids of the nine buttons.
The app shows no error when compiling or running, I just can't set on the buttons the text saved.
I've added some system.out to print the whole `ArrayList` to make sure everything is saved and retrieved correctly but can't figure out why `setText()` can't set the text saved

---

## EDIT #1

As requested this is the code used to get the id of the buttons

```java
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tris, container, false);

    this.ID = getArguments().getInt("id");

    buttons[0][0] = v.findViewById(R.id.b1_1);
    buttons[0][0].setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons[0][1] = v.findViewById(R.id.b1_2);
    buttons[0][1].setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons[0][2] = v.findViewById(R.id.b1_3);
    buttons[0][2].setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons[1][0] = v.findViewById(R.id.b2_1);
    buttons[1][0].setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons[1][1] = v.findViewById(R.id.b2_2);
    buttons[1][1].setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons[1][2] = v.findViewById(R.id.b2_3);
    buttons[1][2].setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons[2][0] = v.findViewById(R.id.b3_1);
    buttons[2][0].setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons[2][1] = v.findViewById(R.id.b3_2);
    buttons[2][1].setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons[2][2] = v.findViewById(R.id.b3_3);
    buttons[2][2].setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}
```

And this is the button xml:

```xml
<Button
  android:id="@+id/b1_1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:textSize="30dp" />
```

There are 9 buttons placed inside 3 `LinearLayouts`

Comment: Where do you declare your `buttons`? Or where do you assign your `buttons`?

Comment: Added requested code by edit

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add SOLVED to the title or body. Simply accepting an answer is sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some test i found out that after any orientation change the activity who host the fragments would restart and initialize 2 new fragment so the `setText` whould set the text on the old fragment and not the one currently displayed, this also explain why `android:freezesText="true"` wasn't working.
So i modified to `onCreate` function in `MainActivity` to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragment1 = FragmentTris.newInstance(1)/*new FragmentTris(1)*/;
        fragment2 = FragmentTris.newInstance(2)/*new FragmentTris(2)*/;

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container1, fragment1, fragment1_tag)
                .replace(R.id.container2, fragment2, fragment2_tag)
                .commit();
    }
    else if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        fragment1 = (FragmentTris) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment1_tag);
        fragment2 = (FragmentTris) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment2_tag);
    }
    if(!fragment1.isInLayout() && !fragment2.isInLayout())
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container1, fragment1, fragment1_tag)
                .replace(R.id.container2, fragment2, fragment2_tag)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

This way after a rotation would be possible use the same instance of the fragments and restore correctly the text on the buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onViewStateRestored(android.os.Bundle)) lifecycle method of `Fragments`.

Just remove the code from `onActivityCreated(Bundle b)` and place all the code inside `onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem:

> ```
> int i = 0;
>
> for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
>     for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
>     {
>         String s = string.get(i);
>         buttons[x][y].setText(s);//<--- Problem here
>     }
> ```

Notice that the value of `i` is never changing. So you're going to fill up all nine buttons with whatever happens to be the first item in your list.

You could solve this by incrementing `i` after each loop:

```
int i = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        String s = string.get(i);
        buttons[x][y].setText(s);
        i++;
    }
```

However, a much easier way to do this would be to let the Android system save the text for you. `TextView`, which is a superclass of `Button`, has the attribute [`android:freezesText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:freezesText). Set this to `true`, and the text will be automatically saved and restored for you.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/b1_1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:freezesText="true"           <---- add this
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Comment: Looks like even the xml attribute  android:freezesText fail to preserve the text